# sqoop import MetaException(message:User user does not have privileges for CREATEDATABASE)

Tags: hive, sqoop

I am trying to import data into hive using sqoop. When I tried this script from one user it worked, but from another user, it fails.

My script is as follows:

```
import
--connect
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/sid
--compression-codec
org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
--username
user
--password
pas
--query
query
--map-column-java
col=String
-hive-import
--hive-overwrite
--hive-drop-import-delims
--hive-database
db
--hive-table
table
--as-parquetfile
--split-by
col
--delete-target-dir
--target-dir
table
-m
1
```

As I understand it, nowhere in this script is a db creation performed. I tried it with and without hive table already present.

Why is it throwing this error (as mentioned in title)?

Answer (score 0):

> nowhere in this script is a db creation performed

It happens. In your below script lines:

```
--hive-database
db
```

Refer Sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html).
Specifically the line:

> The script will be executed by calling the installed copy of hive on the machine where Sqoop is run

Internally Sqoop will call hive to carry out the import. Default authentication mechanism of hive will be used. That exlains why it works with user `A` who would have privileges to `create database` in hive, but fails when invoked by user `B` who may not have that privilege.

Verify by invoking the hive command line and try to run a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.